# In arduino what is SREG?

Tags: c, arduino, avr, atmelstudio

I am trying to convert from arduino to avr-c. I get the error `SREG` is undeclared. Do you know what `SREG` is?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SREG` is the **S**tatus **Reg**ister. It is `#define`'d in one of the AVR headers, so you are probably missing an `#include` (perhaps `avr/io.h` or `avr/common.h`).